# Kafka compacted topic, does retention.ms apply to them?

Tags: apache-kafka

Since we upgraded Kafka from 2.0.0 to 2.3.0, for compacted topics we are seeing in the logs the following message:

```
INFO [Log partition=compactedTopic-40, dir=/data/kafka/kafka] Found deletable segments with base offsets [106539766] due to retention time 432000000ms breach
```

which to me doesn't make much sense when the topics have the policy just set to `compact`.

That `432000000ms` is the broker value of `log.retention.ms` and we are not configuring `retention.ms` in the compacted topics configuration.

Is there any way a compacted topic (with policy set to `compact`, not to `compact,delete`) that can be affected by `log.retention.ms`?

Checking the Kafka source code tells me that the only way to print that message is if config has the `delete` string on it: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/Log.scala#L1576

Is there anyway you can think why we are seeing this message in the logs for compacted topics?

Could this be a bug in Kafka?

Thanks

Comment: Not including the partition map configuration, let me know if you need it.
```Topic:compactedTopic    PartitionCount:32   ReplicationFactor:4 Configs:compression.type=snappy,min.insync.replicas=2,cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=104857600,flush.messages=10000,max.message.bytes=10489860,min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.5,index.interval.bytes=4096,retention.bytes=-1,delete.retention.ms=21600000,segment.ms=86400000,segment.index.bytes=15728640
```

Comment: Thanks. So, you should have upgraded to the patch version of 2.3.1, but I cannot say if that would fix the logs here... I do see that you have `PartitionCount:32`, but the logs indicate that partition 40 is the one being cleaned

Comment: Sorry, that partition 40 is misleading. I took the example from another topic that has 40 partitions.

Comment: We didn't upgrade to 2.3.1 because that version has a regression bug that make the log cleaner threads crash... so we had to do 2.3.0. Are you suggesting that version because it contains a fix related to this issue?

Comment: I'm saying that version should have fixed _something_ in 2.3.0, I don't read the changelog/tickets to really know when/what goes in

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. So, do you think that retention.ms should kick in for compacted topics in any case?

Comment: It shouldn't, no. It might be possible Zookeeper has some bad state about `cleanup.policy`

Comment: Ok, i will check that out

Comment: FYI, zookeeper config was ok. We came to the conclusion that for who knows what reason, the topic config value for "cleanup.policy" that was cached in memory became "compact,delete" for all compacted topics. After updating the topic config, the config is reloaded from zookeeper and the issue is gone.